# GRUB not launching

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot

When I start up my machine it does not go into the boot loader instead I get a black screen which displays this:

```
Intel UNDI, PXE-2.0 (build 083)
Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation

For Atheros PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.1.1.1 (12/23/11)

CLIENT MAC ADDR: 4C 72 B9 D5 1E 94 GUID: ACA2676D-DF96-64OF-67E8-829649E6F1FF

PXE-E53: No boot filename received

PXE-MOF: Exiting Intel PXE ROM

ERROR: No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed.
```

If I go into the BIOS's boot options these are what's listen:

```
UEFI Boot Sources
    Windows Boot Manager
Legacy Boot Sources
    ATAPI CD/DVD Drive
        SATA2
    Hard Drive
        SATA0
    Network Controller (Atheros Boot Agent)
```

I have tried booting from "Windows Boot Manager" and "SATA0" but they both present me with that same screen.

I can launch into my LiveUSB just fine, I have checked the partitions in gparted and this is what they look like:

```
Partition | File System | Size      | Used      | Unused    | Flags
/dev/sda2 | unknown     | 200.00MiB | ---       | ---       | bios_grub
/dev/sda1 | ext4        | 676.94GiB | 12.86MiB  | 664.67MiB | ---
/dev/sda3 | Linux-swap  | 7.94GiB   | ---       | ---       | ---
/dev/sda4 | ntfs        | 246.44GiB | 28.32GiB  | 218.12GiB | ---
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, I installed 12.04LTS the same as I have all my other systems the only differences are that:

1. The NIC is newer than 12.04 so the drivers aren't their out of the box.
2. I'm installing it along side Windows 8

Here's answers to questions I expect to be asked and things I have tried.

**Did you install Windows first?**

Yes.

**Have you tried boot-repair?**

As I cannot connect to the internet I cannot run boot-repair. I made a boot-repair-disk and tried that but it was complaining about not having internet and did not work.

**Have you tried reinstalling GRUB?**

Yes. I tried reinstalling GRUB from the LiveUSB and from `chroot` on the Linux partition, neither worked.

**Have you tried single booting?**

Yes. Single booting works. I can run either OS separately but now that I have tried dual booting the machine (Which is a requirement as this is my dev machine and I need to test the software on both Linux and Windows).

**Have you tried 13.04?**

Yes. I made a 13.04 LiveUSB, that had the drivers for the NIC but wouldn't let me connect to the internet through my work's proxy.

Any help is appreciated, I am desperate now as I cannot work without this machine being functional.

**What is the PC specs?**

The full specs can be found here: http://uk.hardware.info/productinfo/156175/hp-elite-7500-mt-b5g34ea#tab:overview

---

**Edit**

I took the hard drive home and put it in my machine and grub launches just fine? (I get the grub rescue prompt but it's more than I get on the work machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it!

This was all down to UEFI. For some reason my LiveUSB didn't pick up that it needed to install in UEFI mode until I went into the BIOS and disabled Legacy support.